# Finding out what permissions are required by the SQL Server Agent Jobs

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-agent

I've been looking at this for a while and I can't work out an easy way to do this.

As it stands every job in the database runs under SA level rights (horrifying thought)

I'm sure some of the jobs need quite high level rights for what they're doing but I'm also certain quite a lot do not. I was thinking to create 3 or 5 domain accounts to better control the jobs (its not necessary but having them all run SA is personally worrying).

Anyone know a way that this can be done without simply ripping out all the permissions and granting them one by one until I stop getting errors?

Ste

Answer (score 2):

The only way you'll be able to do this consistently and correctly is by looking at what each job does, and cross-referencing that with the msdn articles for each command on your given version.

For example, [DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174384.aspx) has a section:

> **Permissions**
>
> In order to view the statistics object, the user must own the table or
>   the user must be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, the
>   db_owner fixed database role, or the db_ddladmin fixed database role.
>
> *> SQL Server 2012 SP1 modifies the permission restrictions and allows
>   users with SELECT permission to use this command.*
>
> Note that the following requirements exist for SELECT permissions to
>   be sufficient to run the command:   Users must have permissions on all
>   columns in the statistics object   Users must have permission on all
>   columns in a filter condition (if one exists)   The table cannot have
>   a row-level security policy.
>   *To disable this behavior, use traceflag 9485.*

As each command has a different subset of required permissions, and this is at times version dependent, there is no quick and dirty way to determine it that I know of.
(Maybe some tracing could give you the same information faster, but it would also imply monitoring the tasks as they run)

Comment: Yea that's what I'm worried about, a few of the jobs are mazes of stored procedures that just map outwards

Comment: @SteBov Cleaning up a mess after it's already been placed in production is never fun, or easy. But it is the best learning experience.

Comment: yea, there's a lot more easier gains to make still, this is something that's bugging me and I was hoping there might be an easier way without setting aside a month to trail through every single procedure and job (there's only 500 procs to go through, could be a lot worse) :)

Comment: @SteBov Well maybe someone more knowledgeable than me (IE 99% of the regulars here) will come along with some amazing procedure that will drop our jaws ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually reviewing the definitions of the stored procedures I have (with some success) used a dependency tracker like redgate SQL Dependency Tracker. It can help resolving external object used in the procedures.

Comment: How does it work for finding the necessary permissions?

Answer (score 0):

There are [DMVs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677185.aspx) which will allow you to unravel the call stack from any given stored procedure, using a recursive CTE.  Then there are [ways](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345443.aspx) to pull the text for each stored procedure, should you need to have that. There are programatic ways to [parse SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589096/parsing-sql-code-in-c-sharp) if you want to extract the statement (SELECT, INSERT) and the table names, which you likely will if you're trying to minimise rights granted. As these classes are .Net they can be instantiated through Power Shell just as easily as in a C# application.

None of this will help if you have dynamic SQL in the SP, client-side code, queries constructed from stored fragments or other exotica. Calls to system functions (DBCC, DMVs themselves) have different permission sets to the normal schema objects, of course.

As a first step, granting the job credentials db_owner would limit some of the crasser excesses of running as sa.